# How to make scrollbar scroll-able in mobile view chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

I've been searching for `StackOverflow` about my problem, but I didn't find the answer, my problem is, I have `navbar` menu on top of my website which if you open from mobile browser `(chrome, UC browser, etc)` its show the scroll bar and the menu can be scrolled if you touch the menu text (black circle) not the scroll bar (blue circle), my scrollbar can't be drag to scroll the menu, but it can be clicked to drag the menu, here is the picture of the menu

[image: screenshot menu]

and my css is here

```
.classsname{
        height: 300px; 
        overflow-y: scroll;
        position:relative;
        z-index: 0;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
        -webkit-transform:translateZ(0);}
```

what did I do wrong?

EDIT: my full `css` with `header nav`, and `header nav`

on my php

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
    {
      .mean-nav .header-nav{
        height: 300px; 
        overflow-y: scroll;
        position:relative;
        z-index: 0;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
        -webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
      }
    }
```

and i called this css below with this

```
                <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="header-nav clearfix">
                <li class="menu-item <?= $isHome ? 'current-menu-item' : '' ?>"><a title="Home" href="<?= Url::home();?>">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children <?php
                $a = Url::current();
                if((Url::current() == Url::to(['site/about'])) or (strpos($a, 'event')))
                  echo 'current-menu-item';
                ?>"><a title="About">About</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a title="Vision and Mission" href="<?= Url::to(['site/about']) ?>">Vision and Mission</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a title="Event" href="<?= Url::to(['event/index', 'page'=>'1']) ?>">Event</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li> 
                .....
                </ul>
```

and on my `css`

```
  a.meanmenu-reveal{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: 1;
    top:-50px !important;

  }
  .mean-container .mean-bar .mean-nav ul li a.mean-expand{
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 18px !important;
  }
  nav.main-menu{margin-top:0;}
```

Comment: Try this plugin hope it'll solve your problem. https://github.com/HassanUsman/cordova-scrollbar-android

Comment: sorry I forgot to remove the android tag, I used html and css to do this project, the problem is only at mobile view, so I don't use cordova or something like that, is your plugin can be used on html project?

Comment: No, that plugin is only for cordova. You mentioned the `android` tag that's why I commented.

Comment: Try this plugin.... https://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/

Comment: sorry but it also didn't work for me, is it possible only to modify the css without plug in?

Comment: Send me your web url so I can help you

Comment: sorry, but I only do this on my localhost for practice

Comment: ok show your complete `navBar` css

Comment: I already edited the question with the css i used for my navbar menu, which is class header-nav, and id main-menu-main